# Can't add foreign key PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, datagrip

Can't add foreign key to table. DB Graph:
https://pp.vk.me/c638520/v638520058/11d8a/yqKLEPtqNOk.jpg

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE public.row DROP CONSTRAINT statement_section_id_fk;
ALTER TABLE public.row
ADD CONSTRAINT statement_section_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (row_id) REFERENCES statement_section (section_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

No alert, no exceptions, just https://pp.vk.me/c638520/v638520058/11d83/ymwwrM1udhA.jpg

Comment: Just the bug in the third-party client software IMO. PS: use `psql`and `\d public.row` command to see details about your table.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the difference with my example (which works)? https://pp.vk.me/c626724/v626724435/440ad/t0HEnhHFUjI.jpg